# Get File's Epoch timestamp, convert to DateTime, to string, and then to the identical epoch float with microsecond precision

Tags: python, datetime, time, mktime

I want to take a file's epoch timestamp float (e.g., "1661796943.8816772" from `"os.stat(__file__).st_mtime"`), and convert that float to what I think is called a DateTime string, and convert that DateTime string back to a float that is identical to the float I started with, i.e. from `"os.stat(__file__).st_mtime"`.

I think my DateTime string has the precision I want (e.g., "2022,08,29,11,15,43,881677"), and I'm able to convert it to a DateTime object:

```
print(my_DateTime_obj)
>>2022-08-29 11:15:43.881677
```

But the routine I [found](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-in-python/) to convert the DateTime object to an Epoch float lacks a lot of the precision my original float ("1661796943.8816772") had:

```
print(time.mktime(DateTime_obj.timetuple()))
>>1661796943.0
```

I think timetuple() is the problem, but I have not been able to figure it out.
Any tips about how to the convert the DateTime object to an Epoch float, without losing what I think is the microsecond precision, would be much appreciated.
I confess I am still a long way from understanding mktime(), timetuple() and what "structured time" really means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime, timezone

import numpy as np

# file modification time, seconds since Unix epoch
unix0 = os.stat(__file__).st_mtime

# to datetime object
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix0, tz=timezone.utc)
print(dt.isoformat(timespec="microseconds"))
# e.g.
# 2022-08-30T08:31:32.117021+00:00

# datetime object back to Unix time
unix1 = dt.timestamp()

# assert equal with microsecond precision
assert np.isclose(unix0, unix1, atol=1e-6)
```

Note: if you don't set `tz=timezone.utc`, the datetime object will be naive (as opposed to timezone-aware) and resemble local time. The conversion would work correctly nevertheless.

Comment: I apologize for my delay in acknowledging that your code works.  When I run your code in Anaconda Python 3.8.5, I get a bunch of errors, starting with: [C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:138: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import] I'll keep trying to fix it, or to find a virtual python environment online where I can run your code, and I'll acknowledge you're right by tomorrow.

Comment: @MarcB.Hankin the warning you get is caused by numpy; you can avoid it by commenting out the lines that use numpy in my code example. I just put it there for demonstration purpose, it's not necessary for the timestamp conversion to work.